# Understanding Ember araycomputed

Tags: ember.js

This is just to improve my understanding. I am learning ember computed property. I reproduced and modified one of the jsbin in slides by [jonathan goldman](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uFINajo/1/edit)
Here is my code *****
[**JSBIN**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uFINajo/1/edit)

> I understand that as per documents for computed property and aggregated data
>   http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

```
1.The isDone property of any of the objects in the todos array changes.

2.An item is added to the todos array.

3.An item is removed from the todos array.

4.The todos property of the controller is changed to a different array.
```

As in the bin I pasted above If I add or delete any Location the entire list and grouped list both  are updated as expected.

But when I edit any name from the textbox in general list to an existing one the Grouped list is not updated.
Say Initial state of general list is London, New York, Sydney
if I try to change New York to London. the group shows Londo (n missin) and grouping does not happen.

Please find the code below. Incase you want to see working kindly refer to jsbin linked above

```
 App.groupBy = function(dependentKey,property){
  var options = {
    initialValue: Em.A([]),
    initialize: function(initialValue,cm,im){
      return im.previousKeys={};
    },
    addedItem: function(accumulatedValue,item,cm,im){
      var key=item.get(property);
      var group = accumulatedValue.findBy('key',key);
      if(!group){
        group = Em.Object.create({
              key: key,
          numLocation:0 
        }); 
        accumulatedValue.pushObject(group);
      }
      group.incrementProperty('numLocation');
      im.previousKeys[guidFor(item)] = key;
      console.log(accumulatedValue);
      return accumulatedValue;
    },
    removedItem: function(accumulatedValue,item,cm,im){
      var key = item.get(property);
      var group = accumulatedValue.findBy('key',key);
      if(!group){ return; }
      var current = group.decrementProperty('numLocation');
      if(current ===0){
        accumulatedValue.removeObject(group);
      }

      return accumulatedValue;
    }
  };
   return Ember.arrayComputed(dependentKey, options);
};
```

and my IndexController

```
App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({ 
  selected: App.groupBy('model.@each.location','location'),
  actions:{
    addOne: function(){
      this.get('model').pushObject(
        App.Location.create({
          name: this.get('newName'),
          location: this.get('newLocation')
        })
      );
    },
    del:function(obj){
      this.get('model').removeObject(obj);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to post your code here, not somewhere else.

Comment: Hi I have updated code above. Please remove the onHold status